# How to save records in database from layout in mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a common layout for my entire application.  In this layout I have a `contact us` link.  By clicking this link, the user can open a popup form.  This popup is defined in layout page as a `div`.  The user can fill this form out and submit it.  How can I save the form data from this pop up?

Comment: Hi Praveen and welcome to Stack Overflow!  As is, I don't think you've provided enough information for anyone to answer this.  Could you maybe add some information about your actual code?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: layout page is like view,so you can use form post or ajax for save the contact information.

Comment: process it in controller.Action by passing in ContactUsViewModel then save it in database :p

Comment: you can either post it back as a form, or use ajax to do the same. Just because it's in Layout doesn't make that any different to any other form in your application. What have you tried so far? What are you stuck with, exactly?